# MySQL ORDER BY rand(), name ASC

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, random

I would like to take a database of say, 1000 users and select 20 random ones (`ORDER BY rand()`,`LIMIT 20`) then order the resulting set by the names. I came up with the following query which is *not* working like I hoped.

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 ORDER BY rand(), name ASC LIMIT 20`

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: When I try order by rand() limit 3 on a database here of 1600 users I consistently get random results back.

Comment: @vfilby: Yes, now try `order by rand(), name asc` and you'll see that it isn't sorted by name.

Comment: Since secondary order by clause will work only if those rows with same value for the primary sorting column, primary sorting column are all unique values if you use order by rand() first.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
) T1
ORDER BY name
```

The inner query selects 20 users at random and the outer query orders the selected users by name.

Comment: Awesome, two things. Why the `T1` after the query, what's it's purpose? Second: Do you know if it's possible to use a subquery in datamapper?

Comment: Ah, so you're casting that inner select as a new temporary table. Got it.

Comment: @Josh K: Regarding your first question, it's called an alias. If you omit it you get this error: `Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Answer (score 14):

Beware of ORDER BY RAND() because of performance and results.  Check this article out: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: Agree, its possibly the worst performing query.

Comment: Additional WHERE constraints put the RAND load on about at most 500 rows. This is not a huge table, performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using a subquery, you could use two separate queries, one to get the number of rows and the other to select the random rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users; #id is the primary key
```

Then, get a random twenty rows.

```
$start_row = mt_rand(0, $total_rows - 20);
```

The final query:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $start_row, 20;
```

Comment: I believe this should be the correct answer, simply because I think the resources might be lower than calling RAND() or using a 'subquery'.

Comment: You would always get 20 consecutive users ("consecutive" with regard to their names), not 20 random ones.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    users
        WHERE   1
        ORDER BY
                rand()
        LIMIT 20
        ) q
ORDER BY
        name
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
) u
ORDER BY name
```

or a join to itself:

```
SELECT * FROM users u1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
) u2 USING(id)
ORDER BY u1.name
```