# random record from mysql table

Tags: mysql

Is there any built-in function except order by random() to select a random record in mysql table?

Comment: Do you have any certain problem at the moment with your tips and order by random()?

Comment: See similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/alerternative-to-mysql-order-by-rand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868102/order-by-rand-alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882647/mysql-order-by-rand-name-asc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663710/how-does-mysqls-order-by-rand-work

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can make it into two questions. In pseudo-PHP-and-MySQL-code:

```
$max = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example;
$rand = rand(0, $max-1);
SELECT * FROM example LIMIT $rand, 1;
```

The right way would probably be to make it into a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. Actually i dont want to run two select queries as i am using this for displaying tips for user randomly. Is there any other idea?

Comment: @rshivaganesh - this method has *much* better performance than `order by rand()`

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I would go with ORDER BY RAND() on a small table. Maybe you can cache the result from the first query in some way?

Comment: sure. `$rand = rand(0, $max-$num); LIMIT $rand, $num;` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so... why don't you want to use the one that works?

BTW, I'm pretty sure it is `ORDER BY RAND()`.

I've read it can be a performance problem on many rows... do you have many rows?

Comment: no,i have about 1000 tips but i have around 10000 users, it will slow down the process and also the tips are based on category.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() Limit 0, 1;
```

Comment: that should be `LIMIT 0, 1` or `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @nickf does it *really* matter? ;-)

Comment: @nickf :- I edit it but i think 'Limit 1, 1;' also not wrong as he want random data to display.

Comment: what if there's only one row..?

Comment: that's why i edit it but yes then order by rand() will always result same row :)

Comment: Yes, order by rand() will always result one from some set of records