# How do I execute this mysql query with PHP and then randomize the results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am querying one table, but I need four different sets of results, each set having a different type_id

```
SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='1'LIMIT 10;

SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='2'LIMIT 10;

SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='3'LIMIT 10;

SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='4'LIMIT 10;
```

So, I need the most efficient way to make that happen in one query.

Then once it is complete, I need a way to shuffle or randomize the mysqli result object and I am having trouble with that. I would prefer not to use rand in the query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882647/mysql-order-by-rand-name-asc

Answer (score 1):

SQL:

```
SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='1'LIMIT 10
Union
SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='2'LIMIT 10
Union
SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='3'LIMIT 10
Union
SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='4'LIMIT 10;
```

OR you can use IN clause but you won't get 10 of each type_id

```
SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id IN ( '1', '2', '3', '4' ) LIMIT 40;
```

Once you fetch all into an array you can use shuffle.

```
shuffle($arrResults);
```

Comment: The query with `LIMIT 40` doesn't ensure that you get 10 of each type - it would just give you the first 40.

Comment: Yes of coarse, its why i said you won't get 10 of each type_id

Comment: Oh yes, you did! My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the fastest way to get what you want:

```
(SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='1' LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='2' LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='3' LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT item FROM table WHERE type_id ='4' LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY rand();
```

With 40 records, `order by rand()` should be quite fast.

Note that this doesn't get (up to) 40 *random* records.  It gets 40 *arbitrary* records.