# php code for latest entries

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm using this code:

```
<?php
$query1 = "SELECT `tag` FROM  `search` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50";
$query1 = mysql_query($query1);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)){
    $name1 = $row1['tag'];
    $link1 = str_replace(' ','_',$name1);
    $link1 = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '-', $link1);
    $link1 = preg_replace('/-+/', '+', $link1);
    $link1 = $siteurl."download.php?q=".$link1;
    echo '<a href="'.$link1.'" title="'.$name1.'">'.$name1.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
?>
```

The code shows 50 random entries from my table but I want to show latest 50 entries.

Comment: You can add another parameter to `ORDER BY`.

Comment: explain me like a noob, because im not very good with this :D Thanks :)

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND(), ASC|DESC` - the `|` is one or the other. Take your pick ;-)

Comment: So, did that solve the question for you? ^ or is the question still considered "open"?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 125

Comment: What's the exact syntax you're using for it?

Comment: Like this right ? 
$query1 = "SELECT `tag` FROM  `search` ORDER BY RAND(), ASC LIMIT 50";

Comment: *Hm...* try `SELECT MAX(tag) FROM search ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50` and see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/2882647/

Comment: Does the table have an id field? If yes, you can query something like this: SELECT tag FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50. 

If the table doesn't have the id, please add it as an auto-increment field.

Comment: or `SELECT tag FROM search  ORDER BY tag ASC, RAND() LIMIT 50` one of those two should work.

Comment: So did `SELECT MAX(tag) FROM search ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50` or `SELECT tag FROM search ORDER BY tag ASC, RAND() LIMIT 50` work for you?

Comment: Gawd my fingers are cramped up from typing so much.

Comment: Sorry man, webternals solution works for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost answered your own question.

```
$query1 = "SELECT `tag` FROM  `search` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50";
```

This line has RAND() which tells MySQL to get RANDOM Entries.

to get just the last 50 entries you would do

```
$query1 = "SELECT `tag` FROM  `search` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50 ";
```

The default ordering will be by the primary key in most cases that is the Auto Increment value which is most often id. DESC says give them to me in last to first submitted entries if you want them to be in order you will have to do a sub query to reverse them and get them in first submitted order but the last 50 entires.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `search` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC ";
```

or you could do something like

```
$query1 = "(SELECT * FROM `search` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) ORDER BY id ASC";
```