# SQL Sort by RAND and then sort by something else

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, random

I'm trying to fetch data in SQL first by RAND and then order **those random fetched items** by something else, like price.
None of the ways I've tried worked.

```
ORDER BY RAND(`parts`.price) DESC LIMIT 6
```

This, for example, fetches the same items over and over again.

```
ORDER BY RAND(),`parts`.price DESC LIMIT 6
```

This fetches random items, but does not sort them.

```
ORDER BY `parts`.price, RAND() DESC LIMIT 6
```

This fetches same items, not by random and not by price.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2882682/3724365) might help you out

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 6
) T1
ORDER BY `parts`.price
```

Basically you're creating a temporary table with the first query and then sorting it.