# How to optimize a slow SQL statment using RAND()

Tags: php, random

I am currently working on a project that has a very large database of users and their different levels, however we where using RAND() and we are starting to get very high MySQL CPU usage warnings from our web host due to the growing demand of the database.

So we need to optimize this one particular query to help reduce the mysqli calls …

The row **LINK** where most of the data is stored is close to 50,000 + entries and using RAND() is slowly killing the website.

How would we optimize this to reduce the number of mysqli calls..

```
$CALLROW = $db->CacheGetAll("SELECT `ID`, `TITLE` FROM `{$tables['link']['name']}` WHERE (`FEATURED` = '1' OR `FEATURED_ADVANCED`= '1' OR `FEATURED_NORMAL`= '1') AND `STATUS` = '2' {$expire_where} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
$tpl->assign('CALLROW', $CALLROW);
```

How can we reduce the memory imprint on the above SQL statement?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2882956/11430357

Comment: I still cant seem to get it as I am fairley new to php any help would be appreciated and I thank anyone in advance

Comment: You could create a new ordering column and use a background process to write random numbers in that field for all rows. Then ordering by that field will be much less time-expensive.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: Can someone please give us an example of a better sql inquiry then the above one

Answer (score 0):

Well after trial an error I came up with this

```
$CALLROW = $db->CacheGetAll("SELECT * FROM `{$tables['link']['name']}` WHERE `FEATURED` = '1' OR `FEATURED_ADVANCED`= '1' OR `FEATURED_NORMAL`= '1' AND `STATUS` = '2' AND ID >= RAND() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `{$tables['link']['name']}`) LIMIT 15");
$tpl->assign('CALLROW', $CALLROW);
```

However after I refresh it pulls some different ones but never the FEATURED_ADVANCED or FEATURED_NORMAL it seems to only pull the FEATURED IDs first

Any idea of how to truly shuffle these

Comment: I still cant seem to get them to actually shuffle the results... It does randomly select but it never seems to grab the FEATURED_NORMAL or FEATURED_ADVANCED ones any suggestions?